# Upgrading R package goes back to previous version

Tags: r, installation, package

I want to upgrade the R package evaluate from 0.9 to 0.10, so that I can install the R markdown in RStudio. However, I manually removed the evaluate package and install the evaluate_0.10.tgz back, it went back to the 0.9 version. How do I upgrade to 0.10?

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL --build evaluate_0.10.tgz
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library’
* installing *binary* package ‘evaluate’ ...
* ‘evaluate’ was already a binary package and will not be rebuilt
* creating tarball
packaged installation of ‘evaluate’ as ‘evaluate_0.9.tgz’
* DONE (evaluate)
```

Comment: If you have devtools installed you can try `install_version("evaluate", "0.10")`strange that you're getting 0.9, might be a problem with the description file.